# Encoding issues for Arabic letters

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

This form works fine, but am trying to change the 'other' value into some word in Arabic, then as a result the form doesnt work properly, it appears after users choice of a drop down list.

Could it be any encoding issues for arabic letters?

```
<form name="myform">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='other'){this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">3</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
            <input type="textbox" name="other" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please indent correctly. it makes the code easier to interpret.

Comment: did you specify utf8 for your html doc ?

Comment: @franklin, I aproved the edit, but noticed afterwards you left the new title incomplete and didn't add the original title in the content (the info was not there). Check my edit so you see how a full edit works ;)

Comment: Exactly how doesn't the form work properly after inserting an Arabic word?

Comment: By the way, the input should have `type="text"`, not `type="textbox"`.

Comment: <select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='غير'){this.form['غير'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['غير'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
.
.
.
.
<option value="غير">غير</option>

Comment: Please post a complete sample document that does not work as expected, and explain what you expect and how the behavior differs from it.